# When should you use the fail function for streams?

Tags: c++, io, fstream

For my program, I'm supposed to read in a file "sales.txt" that contains a salesperson's name and the dollar amount of a sale. The file is sorted alphabetically so that if a person made multiple sales, their name will appear consecutively with the corresponding dollar amount. Then I'm supposed to print the total sales amount for each salesperson. But my question is: When should I use the fail function for both fin and fout?

```
if(fin.fail())
{ cout << "Error \n";
  exit(1);
}
```

This instructional pdf I read online said that you should never assume that opening a file was successful and therefore should always test that it succeeded before continuing. However, the answer I was provided for this example problem does not include the fail function. Also, what does exit(1) exactly do?

Comment: Read the documentation on [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com): [`fail()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail), [`exit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit).  Also see the [`exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) method, which can be used to make streams throw a [`failure`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) exception you can catch in a `try/catch` handler if a failure actually occurs, rather than manually checking `fail()` each time.

Comment: "However, the answer I was provided for this example problem does not include the fail function." What does it include then? There are other ways of checking if opening a file was successful without explicitly calling the `fail()` function, such as `if (!fin)`.

Answer (score 2):

### Fail

Basically, it checks whether or not it could open/write to the file provided. If it can't, it returns true, and your `if` statement gets executed.

> **std::ios::fail**
> Check whether either failbit or badbit is set
> Returns true if either (or both) the failbit or the badbit error state flags is set for the stream.
> At least one of these flags is set when an error occurs during an input operation.
>
> failbit is generally set by an operation when the error is related to the internal logic of the operation itself; further operations on the stream may be possible.

Also check out this table
[image]

If you look at the fail() column under "functions to check state flags", you'll see that `fail()` returns true under 2 conditions:

1. Logical error on i/o operation
2. Read/writing error on i/o operation (Your case)

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/)

---

### Exit

As for [`exit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/exit/?kw=exit), it simply terminates the program.

> If status is zero or EXIT_SUCCESS, a successful termination status is returned to the host environment.
> If status is EXIT_FAILURE, an unsuccessful termination status is returned to the host environment.

Here's an example in Linux:

```
//test.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   //exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
   std::exit (0);
}
```

Use `$?` in the shell to get the last return code

```
//shell
user: echo $?
output: 0
```

Now try using `EXIT_FAILURE`

```
//test.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   std::exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

```
//shell
user: echo $?
output: 1
```

So in a nutshell, it allows you to exit the program when that line of code is read, and choose to return 0 (exit normally) or 1 (return 1 usually indicates that the program was terminated with an error).

Comment: To clarify: exit(EXIT_FAILURE) is the same as exit(1).    And exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) is the same as exit(0).